# Gathering Active Directory Data for MVC intranet application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, directoryservices

I need assistance with gathering Active Directory data based on a table in my DB. I have an entity class that holds user requests. Each request has the user's windows name from System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name. My problem is I cannot figure out how to setup a linq query to associate the AD username to the rest of the AD so I can display their full names instead of their username in my table. Here is what I have so far, any help will be appreciated.

```
      public partial class RequestInfo
    {
    public int RequestInfoId { get; set; }
    public string RequestByUserADId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime RequestDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }

    public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; } // where I define my custom roles
    }
```

I can query AD by using the code below. I have tried [Get Active Directory User Information With Windows Authentication in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156913/get-active-directory-user-information-with-windows-authentication-in-mvc-4), but it did not help.

```
        using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, requestByAdId))
        {
            return user.DisplayName
        }
```

Comment: Do you have their active directory username so that if you did UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, "youruser"); it will get you the user principal?

Comment: yes. I tested it on mine and I can see fields such as DisplayName, EmailAddress. it returns the proper values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be off here because I am not sure if you are able to successful establish a user principal or not but if you have the user principal you can get property information like the following:

```
user.GetProperty("propertyName")
```

Here is a static method that should get you the department for a user, for example.

```
public static String GetDepartment(UserPrincipal principal)
{
    return principal.GetProperty("department");
}
```

Let me know where this gets you and I can elaborate further if this isn't working.

**Edit**

It appears you need to go one level deeper to get the fields that aren't by default a part of the user principal.  For this you will need to get the directory entry from the user principal first:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = (userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);
```

Then you need to check if the attribute you are looking for exists, and if it does, get the value.  A great way to do this is to create a helper method that you pass your directory entry to along with the string value for the property name that you want to get.

```
public string GetProperty(DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, string propertyName)
{
    if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(propertyName))
    {
        return directoryEntry.Properties[propertyName][0].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Please note that going to the underlying object is expensive.  I believe this operation, by default, is cached for you so subsequent use of this information can be retrieved from cache.  Playing around with

```
directoryEntry.RefreshCache
```

will get you started with that.

Let me know if this does the trick for you!

Comment: I do not see department, but i see EmployeeId, GivenName, LastLogon etc...I printed out all the properties using GetProperties() and there are a bunch.

Comment: still working on trying to get my request entity to join to each users principal so i can pull their name and email address. So when i create a LINQ statement I can make the Display name part of my view model. I am not sure I need to go into the directory. All I need is DisplayName and EmailAddress right now

Comment: so as you mentioned it can be expensive to dive into the directory. I decided to grab the UserPrincipal information when they create a request and store what i need in my database since I only need their name and email. I thought that would be less expensive then querying the UserPrincipal every time. Do you agree with that method?

Comment: I agree completely.  There is definitely nothing wrong with taking that approach.  Getting the user principal is not very expensive.  Make sure to consider when the user changes their information.  It probably wouldn't be too expensive to do the check when they log in to make sure the data hasn't changed.  If you don't need the information updated live that's the way to go.