# Active Directory fields in ASP.NET MVC4 - unhandled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I need to implement a class which retrieves some fields from AD. I've followed the instruction from here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156913/get-active-directory-user-information-with-windows-authentication-in-mvc-4). But I get an unhandled exception from line :

```
return (UserPrincipalExtended)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalExtended), identityValue)
```

My controller code looks like this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
(...)

public class HomeController : Controller
{
   private FormsEntities db = new FormsEntities();

   public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
   {          
        UserPrincipalExtended user = UserPrincipalExtended.FindByIdentity(
        new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), User.Identity.Name);          

        var title = user.Title;        
        ViewBag.Message = title;

        return View();
   }
```

Should I add any additional configuration? In `web.config` for example? I'd like to mention that I successfully implement Windows authentication with AD login and password and the code.

```
string userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1].ToString();
```

shows right user. Also I've tried to manipulate an object type `[DirectoryObjectClass("user")]` but without any result.

Comment: I ve checked             if (null == UserPrincipalExtended.FindByIdentity(
 new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), User.Identity.Name))
            {
                throw new Exception("Some exception");
            } but exception still occures

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend putting your `PrincipalContext` into a `using() { ... }?` block to ensure proper disposal.

Also: whenever you call a method that goes into e.g. Active Directory (or a database, or calls a web service) - then you need to **ensure** that you're actually getting back something valid! Don't just blindly assume the call succeeded - maybe it did - maybe it didn't - **check for success!**

So I would write this index method like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{          
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        UserPrincipalExtended user = UserPrincipalExtended.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);          

        // check FOR NULL ! 
        // Defensive programming 101 - ALWAYS check, NEVER just assume!
        if (user != null) 
        {
            var title = user.Title;        
            ViewBag.Message = title;
        }
        else 
        {
            // handle the case that NO user was found !
            ViewBag.Message = "(no user found)";
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no result.

Comment: I figure it out! for those with similar problems, you need to put user object like that:  using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
                {
           

                    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), User.Identity.Name);