# ASP.NET MVC Windows Authenticate with extending properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I need help of experts!

---

I write ASP.NET MVC 4 Intranet application. I using Windows Authentication, the domain name get through `User.Identity.Name.` I have a database with the configured data context, where more complete information about the user: Last name, First name, E-mail, etc. As well as a list of user access groups.

Needed to make sure that a user open a program, has received the required access from the database, his name brought up in the upper right corner of the page.

Now I have realized that with the use of OWIN Asp.Net Identity. I created a base controller that inherits the other controllers, it ordered *CurrentUser* method for the user and his SignIn:

```
protected ApplicationUser CurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        var curUser = AppUserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
        if (curUser != null)
            SignInManager.SignIn(curUser, true, true);
        else
            curUser = new ApplicationUser();

        return curUser;
    }
}

protected ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    }
}
```

I understand that these operations are unnecessary, when you refresh the page every time it is necessary to drag into the database, users receive and make SignIn, which is unnecessary.

I'm sure you can realize all without using Asp.Net Identity. For example by expanding `IPrincipal User`, adding him to the field name, which are needed when displaying pages and adding once Roles from the database and save all in Cookies.

Please, help me! And sorry for my bad english...

Comment: See my answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156913/get-active-directory-user-information-with-windows-authentication-in-mvc-4/20380152#20380152. All the info you're storing separately is already in AD, you just need to extend `UserPrincipal`.

Comment: In addition to the data stored in AD, I have custom access groups that are stored in the database.

Comment: Can somebody help me?