# Get current logged in user's email address is timming out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

I am using the Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).Email method to try and get the current user email address but its timing out, I just have one line, on which I declare and assign the returned value of the method to a variable
Here is my one line of code `string userEmail = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).Email;`,

I have tried this code both with or without the username parameter. I also tried checking first if user is authenticated but once it gets to this line it times out, I have also tried doing it totally from a different method.

Note: Windows auth is used on the web app

Comment: check if database connection is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Membership` is from ASP.NET Membership, not Identity. You need to use:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Then, you access the `Email` property off that user object.

**UPDATE**

I got thrown by your use of the [asp.net-identity] tag. However, the same over all point applies. `Membership` is from a completely different authentication system than Windows Auth. When using Windows Auth, your user information comes from AD, so you simply need to add a `UserPrincipal` extension if you need additional information. See [my answer in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20380152/654031).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris Pratt this helped a lot, there is actually an existing AD service in my organisation, I just used it to get all the AD-user related info, you answer pointed me to the right direction